# How to display google api response photo in react.js

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

I made a call to the Google places API that sent back a photo. How do I display this in an IMG object?

the response photo is as follows

[Link to response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44iSn.png)

Comment: Did you check the type of response? If that is a data stream you can show the image.

Comment: Try this one. `<img src={URL.createObjectURL(responseData)} />` put your response into responseData. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hey, tried it out, but it says: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: `window.URL.createObjectURL(responseData)` Maybe you have to get it from the window like this.

Comment: Don't forget to add this using axios, add {responseType: 'blob'} to the config